# How to output such data in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

tell me how to output data if their syntax is like this. This data is contained in the child component, and it must be output to the parent component. I know that you need to use props, I am interested in another, what syntax you need to output all the data. Using the Vue CLI

```
 this.anyOldBundes = [
    new BundleItem({
price: 7.5,
name: '2GB',
id: ''1248,
color: 'red'
}),
 new BundleItem({
price: 7.5,
name: '2GB',
id: ''1248,
color: 'red'
}),
 new BundleItem({
price: 7.5,
name: '2GB',
id: ''1248,
color: 'red'
})
]
```

Comment: **props** is used for transfer data from parent to child. from child to parent, uses `event` will be an option. check [Vue Guide: Event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) for more detail.

Comment: I've heard about it. Can you give the code how can I pass it?

Answer (score 0):

in the child component you can emit an event like:

`this.$emit('someEvent', this.anyOldBundes)`

and then in the parent upon the child component it should be like:

`<child-component @someEvent="someMethod(data)" />`

```
// methods

someMethod(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```